# ParsePy AttributeError: 'Date' object has no attribute '_date'

Tags: python, python-2.7, parse-platform, kivy, parsepy

I am trying to save a date from a Kivy app to a parse.com database using ParsePy and its Date() class.

For example, I create a date attribute for a restaurant object with:

`restaurant.date = Date('%2014-%11-%15%0:%0:%0.%0%0')`

However, when I try to save this to the database (with restaurant.save()), I get the error:

`AttributeError: 'Date' object has no attribute '_date'`.

[Here](https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy/blob/master/parse_rest/datatypes.py) is the link to the ParsePy Date() class I'm trying to use. How do I properly save a date using this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing the following:

```
import datetime

restaurant.date = Date(date=datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 15))
```